# How to configure ReportPortal for Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, reportportal

I'm using Android studio and gradle to build apk and perform regression testing. I'm supposed to explore ways of integrating ReportPortal to the android project for generating reports. However I didn't find Android Platform listed in https://reportportal.io/installation

I'm open to suggestions about trying out other reporting tools for android studio as well.

Answer (score 1):

Report Portal supports Android testing for JUnit 5 only. You can find corresponding agent and installation instructions in 'agent-android' project: https://github.com/reportportal/agent-android

But I personally recommend to start from our examples:

- Kotlin: https://github.com/reportportal/android-kotlin-example
- Java: https://github.com/reportportal/android-java-example